# Element.insert at bottom-1 with prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I want to insert an Element at the position bottom -1 of his parent.

The following code insert at the bottom

```
el.insert({bottom: content})
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert it "before the last child element" like this:

```
el.select('*').last().insert({before:content});
```

`el.select('*')` gives the child elements in a nice prototype-extended collection.

`last()` of course retrieves the last element of that collection. You might want to retrieve it separately and make sure it is not `undefined` (which is what will be returned if there are no children) before attempting to "insert before it".

Also, IMO it feels better to pass in a non-wildcard selector if possible. For example, when the containing element is an `<ul>`, pass in `'li'`.

Links:
[Prototype Element#insert](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element.html#insert-class_method)
[Prototype Array#last](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/array.html#last-instance_method)

Comment: Does insert still work in Prototype 1.6? Can't find it in the retardedly-organized new API doc.

Comment: Yeah sure, it's a corner stone in the Prototype DOM API I think. Look here: http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element/insert/